# Django and Elastic Beanstalk URL health checks

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django webapp. It runs inside Docker on Elastic Beanstalk.

I'd like to specify a [health check URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html#using-features.managing.elb.healthchecks) for slightly more advanced health checking than "can the ELB establish a TCP connection".

Entirely reasonably, the ELB does this by connecting to the instance over HTTP, using the instance's hostname (e.g. `ec2-127-0-0-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) as the `Host` header.

Django has [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) which validates the `Host` header of incoming requests. I set this to my application's external domain via environment variable.

Unsurprisingly and entirely reasonably, Django thus rejects ELB URL health checks due to lack of matching `Host`.

We don't want to disable `ALLOWED_HOSTS` because we'd like to be able to  trust [`get_host()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host).

The solutions so far seem to be:

- Somehow persuade Django to not care about `ALLOWED_HOSTS` for certain specific paths (i.e. the health check URL)
- Do something funky like calling the EC2 info API on startup to get the host's FQDN and append it to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Neither of these seem particularly pleasant. Can anyone recommend a better / existing solution?

(For the avoidance of doubt, I believe this problem to be identical to the scenario of "Disabled `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, fronting HTTPD that filters on host" - I want the health check to hit *Django*, not a fronting HTTPD)

Answer (score 12):

If the ELB health check is sending its request with a host header containing the elastic beanstalk domain (*.elasticbeanstalk.com, or an EC2 domain *.amazonaws.com) then the standard `ALLOWED_HOSTS` can still be used with a wildcard entry of `'.amazonaws.com'` or `'.elasticbeanstalk.com'`.

In my case I received standard ipv4 addresses as the health check hosts, so a different solution was needed. If you can't predict the host at all, and it might be safer to assume you can't, you would need to take a route such as one of the following.

You can use Apache to handle approved hosts instead of propagating ambiguous requests to Django. Since the host header is intended to be the hostname of the server receiving the request, this solution changes the header of valid requests to use the expected site hostname. With elastic beanstalk you'll need to configure Apache using `.ebextensions` as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html). Under the `.ebextensions` directory in your project root, add the following to a .config file.

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/eb_healthcheck.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <If "req('User-Agent') == 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0' && %{REQUEST_URI} == '/status/'">
            RequestHeader set Host "example.com"
        </If>
```

Replacing `/status/` with your health check URL and `example.com` with your site's appropriate domain. This tells Apache to check all incoming requests and change the host headers on requests with the appropriate health check user agent that are requesting the appropriate health check URL.

If you would really prefer not to configure Apache, you could write a custom middleware to authenticate health checks. The middleware would have to override Django's [`CommonMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py) which calls `HttpRequest`'s `get_host()` method that validates the request's host. You could do something like this

```
from django.middleware.common import CommonMiddleware


class CommonOverrideMiddleware(CommonMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not('HTTP_USER_AGENT' in request.META and request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0' and request.get_full_path() == '/status/'):
            return super().process_request(request)
```

Which just allows any health check requests to skip the host validation. You'd then replace `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` with `path.CommonOverrideMiddleware` in your `settings.py`.

I would recommend using the Apache configuration approach to avoid any details in the middleware, and to completely isolate Django from host issues.

Comment: The Apache method was the only thing that worked for me after trying several strategies.

Comment: Great suggestion about the apache. I would like to say in addition that the user agent string at this time of writing is "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0". A person implementing this approach should check the /var/log/httpd/access_log for the up to date user agent string.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use, and it works well:

```
import socket
local_ip = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
ALLOWED_HOSTS=[local_ip, '.mydomain.com', 'mydomain.elasticbeanstalk.com' ]
```

where you replace `mydomain` and `mydomain.elasticbeanstalk.com` with your own.

Comment: Works for me as well. I wonder if this gives the same result as getting the local ip from the instance metadata using `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`?

Comment: I wonder if the solution proposed here: https://hashedin.com/blog/5-gotchas-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-django/ is better in terms of security?